# AWS S3 presigned upload: How can my server validate that the upload was completed?

Tags: validation, amazon-web-services, file-upload, amazon-s3

Right now this is how the dataflow goes:

1. user gets S3 presigned post from app server
2. user uploads the document to S3
3. on success, the browser app sends a POST to the app server, telling it the upload is complete
4. the app server adds a database entry with the file upload meta data (S3 key, URL etc..)

I'm wondering whether there's a way to validate the POST request in step 3, to make sure the file was actually uploaded (and that I'm not creating a database entry for a file that isn't uploaded).

**Is there a way to do that?**

Right now the only thing I can think of is querying the S3 API from the app server after every POST request from step 3, to make sure the document is where the POST request says it is. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `success_action_redirect` URL to the form, which will cause S3 to redirect the browser back to your server when the upload is complete.   When your server sees this URL accessed, that's confirmation of a successful upload.  Of course, the URL should contain some kind of unique identifier so that you can coordinate it to the specific upload.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPOST.html

There exists the possibility of errors occurring at just the wrong time, causing the browser failing to be able to follow the redirect even though the upload succeeded but if the redirect URL is not, it should only be because the upload succeeded.

Additionally, as you noticed, S3 has internal callback events that can fire when uploads complete.

[Does Amazon S3's HTTP Uploads feature support web-hook style callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2777597/does-amazon-s3s-http-uploads-feature-support-web-hook-style-callbacks)

Comment: but then let's say you have it redirect to `/upload/success?file_id=1234&key=myfile.png`. What's to stop some from abusing that URL? How can I be certain that the visitor to this URL has been redirected from S3?

Comment: You definitely need to include some kind of [nonce](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce)  in the URL so that it wouldn't be abusable.  This mechanism was introduced before the S3 events were rolled out.  I'm not suggesting that it is better, or more correct, but only that it is available.